# kendo ui resize column

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using the following function(which i got from web) to resize the column in kendo ui.
this is based on Index, i am looking out to see if there can be an option to select by column title or field/key.

when i reorder the grid column, this function fails.

```
 function resizeColumn(idx, width) {
            $("#grid .k-grid-header-wrap") //header
               .find("colgroup col")
               .eq(idx)
               .css({ width: width });

            $("#grid .k-grid-content") //content
               .find("colgroup col")
               .eq(idx)
               .css({ width: width });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resize by column title, you just need to figure out the correct index, e.g. like this:

```
function resizeColumn(title, width) {
    var index = $("#grid .k-grid-header-wrap").find("th:contains(" + title + ")").index();

    $("#grid .k-grid-header-wrap") //header
        .find("colgroup col")
        .eq(index)
        .css({ width: width });

    $("#grid .k-grid-content") //content
        .find("colgroup col")
        .eq(index)
        .css({ width: width });
}
```

Comment: This solution only works if there are no locked columns. (because of locked columns are in different colgroup, so indexing must deal with it)

Comment: For anyone looking to use this to enforce a minimum width, make sure to change the columns width in the column object (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns). Otherwise, adding a column will re-shrink the column.

Answer (score 2):

Search column by field id to make sure that is the corrected field.

```
function resizeColumn(fieldId, width) {
    var index = $('#grid .k-grid-header-wrap').find('th[data-field="' + fieldId + '"]').index();

    $("#grid .k-grid-header-wrap") //header
        .find("colgroup col")
        .eq(index)
        .css({ width: width });

    $("#grid .k-grid-content") //content
        .find("colgroup col")
        .eq(index)
        .css({ width: width });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[click here to get complete Answer](http://blogs.planetsoftware.com.au/paul/archive/2013/04/10/extending-kendo-grid-functionality-with-knockout.aspx)

**Loading Column State**

```
function loadColumnState(columnStateKey: string, realGrid): void
{  
    var colState = JSON.parse($.jStorage.get(columnStateKey));

    if(colState && colState.length > 0) 
    {
        var visibleIndex = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < colState.length; i++) 
        {                
            var column = colState[i];

            // 1. Set correct order first as visibility and width both depend on this.                                     
            var existingIndex = -1;

            if (typeof column.field !== 'undefined')
            {
                existingIndex = findFieldIndex(realGrid, column.field);
            }
            else if (typeof column.commandName !== 'undefined')
            {
                existingIndex = findCommandIndex(realGrid, column.commandName);
            }

            if (existingIndex > -1 && existingIndex != i) // Different index
            {   // Need to reorder
                realGrid.reorderColumn(i, realGrid.columns[existingIndex]);
            }

            // 2. Set visibility state
            var isHidden = (typeof column.hidden === 'undefined') ? false : column.hidden;

            if (isHidden) 
            { 
                realGrid.hideColumn(i); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                realGrid.showColumn(i); 
                ++visibleIndex;
            }

            // 3. Set width
            var width = (typeof column.width === 'undefined') ? null :     column.width;

            if(width != null)
            {
                realGrid.columns[i].width = width; // This sets value, whilst rest redraws
                realGrid.thead.prev().find('col:eq(' + visibleIndex + ')').width(width);
                realGrid.table.find('>colgroup col:eq(' + visibleIndex +     ')').width(width); 
            }                              
        }
    }    
}
```